# How to put an InlineFormSet into a ModelFormSet in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'd like to display a number of forms via a `ModelFormSet` where each one of the forms displays in turn `InlineFormSets` for all objects connected to the object.

Now I'm not really sure how to provide the instances for each `ModelFormSet`. I thought about subclassing `BaseModelFormSet` but I have no clue on where to start and would like to know whether this is possible at all before I go through all the trouble.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article which focuses on the exact problem. It works fine!

http://yergler.net/blog/2009/09/27/nested-formsets-with-django/

For the sake of completeness I copied the code fragments:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Building(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Tenant(models.Model):
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=255)

form django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory, BaseInlineFormSet

TenantFormset = inlineformset_factory(models.Building, models.Tenant, extra=1)

class BaseBuildingFormset(BaseInlineFormSet): 

    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        # allow the super class to create the fields as usual
        super(BaseBuildingFormset, self).add_fields(form, index)

        # created the nested formset
        try:
            instance = self.get_queryset()[index]
            pk_value = instance.pk
        except IndexError:
            instance=None
            pk_value = hash(form.prefix)

        # store the formset in the .nested property
        form.nested = [
            TenantFormset(data=self.data,
                            instance = instance,
                            prefix = 'TENANTS_%s' % pk_value)]

BuildingFormset = inlineformset_factory(models.Block, models.Building, formset=BaseBuildingFormset, extra=1)
```

Comment: How could I modify the code if my Buildings don't belong to a Block model? i.e. I'd like to be able to pass initial data of Buildings (or a queryset of Buildings) that would then display Tenants underneath. Look forward to hearing your ideas.

Comment: You could use `modelformset_factory` with your initial queryset of buildings instead of the `inlineformset_factory`.

Comment: @jnns: i have also the same problem which u explained in Ur question, but in your solution I'm not seeing usage of modelformset, how can i generate multiple forms, where each form displays the related inline forms? here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929355/combine-modelformset-and-inlineformset-in-django-views/11929680#comment15888609_11929680

Comment: Just replace `inlineformset_factory` with `modelformset_factory` where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As jnns said, you want to use [inlineformset_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)