# combine modelformset and inlineformset in django views

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

i have two models

```
   class A(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(50)
        type = models.CharField(50)

   class B(models.Model):
        field1 = ForeignKeyField(A)
        value = IntegerField()
```

I'd like to display a number of forms via a ModelFormSet (from model A) where each one of the forms displays in turn InlineFormSets (from model B) for all objects connected to the object.

How can i combine both modelformsets (model A) and inline formsets (mdoel B) on save method in django views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good solution, but it's the only solution I can come up with that will work.

I would create a List of Dictionaries. Each Dictionary will have a baseForm key which will hold your B class form and a inline_forms key which will hold your class A inline_formset.

In your view code iterate over the list and print the forms accordingly. Generate a different value for each of the forms submit button. 
For example submit_1 for the first form , etch ..

When a form is submitted, check this value (the value of the submit button), if the value is for example submit_2 you are certain the second item/form of your list has been submitted. 
From their you can start processing the submitted data.

Comment: which means for 10 forms i need to generate 10 submit buttons?

Comment: Yes, that's what you asked for not ? To have multiple forms on one page. And each individual form needs a submit button, else it can't be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with this a week ago. I would suggest you start using the inlineformset_factory method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Then just add your base form and your formset to your view and render them.

Here's some blog post that helped me figure this out: http://charlesleifer.com/blog/djangos-inlineformsetfactory-and-you/

There's also a solution to make it work using Class Based Views: http://haineault.com/blog/155/

Comment: I think these links will describing only one form and related inline formsets. But i want number of forms via a ModelFormSet (from model A) where each one of the form displays in turn InlineFormSets (from model B) for all objects connected to the object

Comment: So you want a formset of inlineformsets. Is this number of forms with inline formsets fixed or dynamic ?

Comment: yes it is dynamic. I want modelformset for model A then inline formsets for each form of modelformset