# Change the name attribute of form field in django template using

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have form field **{{form.item}}** which will render to

```
        <input type="text" name="item" >
```

How can i change the name attribute of the form field using custom template tags?

I tried by sending the form to template tag where

```
       form.fields['item'].widget.attrs['name'] = 'new_name'
```

But I'm not getting success.

I need to change the name attribute in template.

**UPDATE**

**models.py**

```
class A(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(50)
     type = models.CharField(50)

class B(models.Model):
     field1 = ForeignKeyField(A)
     value = IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
 def saving_calculation(request):

    SavingFormset = modelformset_factory(A, extra=2)
    OfferInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
                     A, B,
                     extra = 4
                     )

   if request.method == 'POST':
      pass
   else:
       offer_formset = OfferInlineFormSet()
       saving_formset = SavingFormset(queryset=SavingCalculation.objects.none()) 

   return render_to_response(
       'purchasing/saving_calculation.html',
       {
       'offer_formset':offer_formset,
       'saving_formset':saving_formset,
       }
```

**template**

```
  <form action="." method="POST">
  {{ offer_formset.management_form }}
  {{ saving_formset.management_form }}
  {{ saving_formset.prefix }}
  <table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Business Unit</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Buyer</th>
    <th>Offer1</th>
    <th>Offer2</th>
    <th>Offer3</th>
    <th>Offer4</th>
    </tr>
     </thead>
 <tbody>
        {% for saving in saving_formset.forms %}
     <tr>
    <td>{{saving.businessunit}}</td>
    <td>{{saving.type_of_purchase}}</td>
    <td>{{saving.buyer}}</td>
    {% for offer in offer_formset.forms %}
        <td>{{ offer|set_field_attr:forloop.counter0 }}</td>
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}

     {% endfor %}

      </tbody>
     </table>
     <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
```

Now in custom template tag i need to assign new name for each field of inline formset

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override Django form field's name attr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801910/override-django-form-fields-name-attr)

Comment: Why do you want to change the name? What makes you think you need this?

Comment: Er, what? Neither of those are a reason to use dynamic names. Explain your use case, and why it isn't covered by the standard view/formset structure.

Comment: @Daniel : I want to achieve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929355/combine-modelformset-and-inlineformset-in-django-views

Answer (score 6):

I've tested this a few different ways, and it works with many types of Form Fields.

Use `set_field_html_name(...)` on every Field you want to set the name on.

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def set_field_html_name(cls, new_name):
    """
    This creates wrapper around the normal widget rendering, 
    allowing for a custom field name (new_name).
    """
    old_render = cls.widget.render
    def _widget_render_wrapper(name, value, attrs=None):
        return old_render(new_name, value, attrs)

    cls.widget.render = _widget_render_wrapper

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField()
    # After creating the field, call the wrapper with your new field name.
    set_field_html_name(field1, 'new_name')

    def clean_field1(self):
        # The form field will be submit with the new name (instead of the name "field1").
        data = self.data['new_name']
        if data:
            raise ValidationError('Missing input')
        return data
```

Answer (score 5):

```
form.fields['new_name'] = form.fields['item']
del form.fields['item']
```

Comment: @Sergy : I already tried this one, but in my case this will not work because i'm dealing with formset

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_name'].label = "New Field name"
```

Comment: this changes the field label, not the field name (the "NAME" part of `<input name="NAME"/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.forms.widgets import Input, TextInput


class CustomInput(Input):
    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super(CustomInput, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
            if context['widget']['attrs'].get('name') is not None:
                context['widget']['name'] = context['widget']['attrs']['name']
        return context


class CustomTextInput(TextInput, CustomInput):
    pass


class ClientLoginForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(label='CustomLabel', widget=CustomTextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','name': 'CustomName'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass any widget class what you need and create your own "render method".
Examples are in the PATH_TO_YOUR_DJANGO/django/forms/forms.py

```
class CustomNameTextInput(TextInput):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if 'name' in attrs:
            name = attrs['name']
            del attrs['name']
        return super(TextInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)


class MyForm(Form):
    item = CharField(widget=CustomNameTextInput, attrs={'name':'my_name'})
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are specifying new name for field name attribute

Answer (score 0):

Another way, creating a custom input that accepts a new parameter called "name" [I also created a custom field that uses this input]:

```
class CustomNameTextInput(forms.TextInput):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = kwargs.pop('name')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs, renderer):
        return super().render(self.name, value, attrs, renderer)


class ElementField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.widget = CustomNameTextInput(name='name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
def set_field_html_name(cls, new_name):
    """
    This creates wrapper around the normal widget rendering, 
    allowing for a custom field name (new_name).
    """
    old_render = cls.widget.render
    def widget_render_wrapper(name, value, attrs=None,renderer=None):
        return old_render(new_name, value, attrs,renderer=None)

    cls.widget.render = widget_render_wrapper
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem.