# Set name attribute in Django generated select field

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm trying to write forms using Django but I don't manage to set the name of Select field.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    successor = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(
        attrs = {'name': 'to_player', 'onclick':'this.form.submit();'}
        )
    )
```

Gives this output:

```
<label for="id_successor">Successor:</label>
<select id="id_successor" name="successor" onclick="this.form.submit();"></select>
```

but should be name="to_player" not name="successor". Why?

Comment: There is a much simpler answer to your question. Check [this][1] post out..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801910/override-django-form-fields-name-attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `name` attribute can't be overwritten using `attrs` because of the way the widget is rendered. However, if you check out [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14498608/1025963), you will find a wrapper function that will allow you to specify your own name attribute.

Answer (score 2):

**I resolved this problem using javascript.**

You can add id attribute in your form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    successor = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs = {'id':'id_player', 'name': 'to_player','onclick':'this.form.submit();'} ))
```

And at the end of the template you can put this javascript code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>

<body>
...
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
document.getElementById('id_player').name = 'to_player';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this way I solved this problem., and works 100% !

Have a nice day !